# How to compare data frame with a factor as a variable?

Tags: r

I have a data frame, please see below.
How do I compare the Volume where `Purchase == 1` to the previous `Purchase == 1` Volume and create a factor variable `V1` like shown in the `Picture 2`?

The `df[5,"V1"] == 1` because `df[5,"Volume"] > df[3,"Volume"]`.... and so on.

How to achieve this without using loops, how do I achieve this the vectorized way so calculation speed is faster(when dealing with millions of rows)?

I've tried sub-setting, then do the comparison but when tried to put them back to a factor variable, the number of rows of the result is not the same as the number of rows of the `df` therefore I cannot put the factor variable to the dataframe.

**Picture 2**

```
       Volume  Weight Purchase     V1
1     3.95670 5.27560        0      0
2     3.97110 5.29280        0      0
3     3.97200 5.29120        1      0
4     3.98640 5.31160        0      0
5     3.98880 5.31240        1      1
6     3.98700 5.31040        0      0
7     3.98370 5.31080        0      0
8     3.98580 5.31400        0      0
9     3.98670 5.31120        1      0
10    3.98460 5.29040        0      0
11    3.97710 5.28920        0      0
12    3.96720 5.26080        1      0
13    3.95190 5.26520        0      0
14    3.95160 5.26840        0      0
15    3.95340 5.26360        1      0
16    3.95370 5.23600        1      1
17    3.93450 5.23480        0      0
18    3.93480 5.23640        1      0
19    3.92760 5.23600        0      0
20    3.92820 5.22960        1      0
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: I expect an output of 1 for the variable `V1`. I am trying to compare the Volume of `Purchase == 1` to the previous Volume of `Purchase == 1`, if it's greater, `V1 == 1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With data.table:

```
library(data.table)
data <- data.table(read.table(text='       Volume  Weight Purchase     V1
                              1     3.95670 5.27560        0      0
                              2     3.97110 5.29280        0      0
                              3     3.97200 5.29120        1      0
                              4     3.98640 5.31160        0      0
                              5     3.98880 5.31240        1      1
                              6     3.98700 5.31040        0      0
                              7     3.98370 5.31080        0      0
                              8     3.98580 5.31400        0      0
                              9     3.98670 5.31120        1      0
                              10    3.98460 5.29040        0      0
                              11    3.97710 5.28920        0      0
                              12    3.96720 5.26080        1      0
                              13    3.95190 5.26520        0      0
                              14    3.95160 5.26840        0      0
                              15    3.95340 5.26360        1      0
                              16    3.95370 5.23600        1      1
                              17    3.93450 5.23480        0      0
                              18    3.93480 5.23640        1      0
                              19    3.92760 5.23600        0      0
                              20    3.92820 5.22960        1      0', header=T))
data[, V1 := 0]
data[Purchase == 1, V1 := as.integer(Volume > shift(Volume)) ]
data[, V1 := as.factor(V1)]
```

Here, I filtered data to where Purchase = 1, then I brought previous Volume with shift function. 
Finally, I compared Volume to Previous volume and assigned 1 if Volume is larger than Previous.

Comment: Exactly what I'm looking for, thanks. Btw, what does `:=` mean in the codes?

Comment: It's a data.table function that creates or modifies a column. 
It assigns right hand side to left hand side. For more detail, you can read https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/r/849/data-table#t=201705231144483877449 page.